# bibtex-style "angewandte" and double citations

Tags: bibtex

I would like to use double citations with the BibTeX style `angewandte` (chemie). In the readme file this is explained:

> For double citations in the style of Angewandte Chemie (German of international edition) the second literature citation can be given with the BibTeX fields `twojournal`, `twovolume` and `twopages`. For the year the field `year` is used!

However, I don't understand these instructions. Can somebody help me in this case?

Edit: I simply downloaded the bst-file from https://chemieunser.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/bibtex-stil-fur-die-angewandte-chemie/ , put it in the folder of my tex-file and use include with the following commands (only the most important listed):

```
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{angewandte}
\bibliography{master_references}
```

Comment: For those of us not already familiar with this particular bibliography style: What's the exact name of the style file, and is this file available on the CTAN?

Comment: For non-chemists: _Angewandte Chemie_ is published in English and German. Historically, the two editions had different articles, then the same articles but different pages. They like us to cite both editions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style linked to comes with a demo file which shows the bibliography entry should be given in the form

```
@ARTICLE{Ache1989,
  author = {H. J. Ache},
  journal = {Angew. Chem.},
  year = {1989},
  volume = {101},
  pages = {1-21},
  timestamp = {2012.04.27},
  twojournal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
  twopages = {1-20},
  twovolume = {28}
}
```

where the `two...` entries are used for the second version. This leads to a minimal example something like

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Ache1989,
  author = {H. J. Ache},
  journal = {Angew. Chem.},
  year = {1989},
  volume = {101},
  pages = {1-21},
  twojournal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
  twopages = {1-20},
  twovolume = {28}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\begin{document}
\cite{Ache1989}
\bibliographystyle{angewandte}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

There are two *Angew. Chem.* styles on CTAN, my own `angew` style, part of the [`rsc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rsc) package and the `ChemEurJ` style, part of the [`chembst`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chembst) bundle. My style does not attempt anything 'clever' for *Angewandte* citations while `ChemEurJ` offers the `germanpages` concept:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Ache1989,
  author = {H. J. Ache},
  journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
  year = {1989},
  volume = {28},
  pages = {1-20},
  germanpages = {1-21},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{mciteplus}
\begin{document}
\cite{Ache1989}
\bibliographystyle{ChemEurJ}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Both of these rely on a fixed relationship between the two editions: they won't work if the paper happens to be in one year in English and a different year in German.

If you are willing to consider `biblatex` then he `chem-angew` style (part of the [`biblatex-chem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) bundle, again written by me) offers a way to link two independent database entries:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Ache1989,
  author = {H. J. Ache},
  journal = {Angew. Chem},
  year = {1989},
  volume = {101},
  pages = {1-21},
  related     = {Ache1989a},
  relatedtype = {translatedas},
}

@ARTICLE{Ache1989a,
  author = {H. J. Ache},
  journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
  year = {1989},
  volume = {28},
  pages = {1-20},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Ache1989}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This has the advantage that each entry is therefore usable on it's own in other styles. (I provide a bundle of `biblatex` styles but have only added this linking to the `chem-angew` style as other publishers do not do this routinely.)