# References formating with bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I use bibtex and pdflatex on mac. The requirements for citation I need to match is

1. References are numbered and
2. numbered by occurence in the text
3. [1,2,3] shall be compressed to [1-3]
4. The reference style shall be 
   [image]

I am using currently

`\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`

That fulfills 1.-3. but however the style is wrong it looks like
[image]

instead.

> How can I get now the correct reference styles?

Comment: Since you explicitly say that you use BibTeX in the question I replaced the tag `biblatex` by BibTeX. (`biblatex` uses a different method to generate citations and the bibliography that does not rely on `\bibliographystyle`.)

Comment: You're right, thank you, sorry for the mistake!

Comment: About your question. It is hard to tell from just one example entry, but the example looks similar to what some Chemistry styles produce, maybe one of the `.bst` files from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chembst, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/achemso or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rsc can help you.

Comment: In particular this looks very similar to the style of *Angewandte Chemie*, two possible styles are discussed in the answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223334/35864

Comment: Yes that is what I need! I forgot how to install these .ins packages any hint how or where to find it :-)?

Comment: OK I got it again, sorry for asking. (one needs to pdflatex the .ins then you get the .bst, which can be moved to any directory that is "visible" to your pdflatex e.g. "."), ( I am getting old, that is: impatient)).

Comment: There should be no need to run the `.ins` files. Both `rsc` (and thus `angew.bst`) as well as `chembst` (and thus `ChemEurJ.bst`) are available via the package managers of TeX live and MikTeX. Just install them with `tlmgr`/TeX Live Utility (TeX live) or the MikTeX Console. **Do not install packages manually unless absolutely necessary.**

Answer (score 1):

The picture looks very similar to the *Angewandte Chemie* style.

There are at least two BibTeX styles for *Angewandte Chemie* on CTAN.

1. `angew.bst` in [`rsc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/rsc).

   ```
   \documentclass[british]{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{babel}

   \usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}

   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @article{becke,
     author  = {Becke, Axel D.},
     title   = {Density-functional thermochemistry. {III.}
                {The} role of exact exchange},
     journal = {J. Chem. Phys.},
     volume  = {98},
     number  = {7},
     pages   = {5648-5652},
     year    = {1993},
     doi     = {10.1063/1.464913},
   }
   @article{perdew,
     title   = {Generalized Gradient Approximation Made Simple},
     author  = {Perdew, John P. and Burke, Kieron and Ernzerhof, Matthias},
     journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
     volume  = {77},
     number  = {18},
     pages   = {3865-3868},
     year    = {1996},
     month   = 8,
     doi     = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865},
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}
   \cite{perdew,becke}
   \bibliographystyle{angew}
   \bibliography{\jobname}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. `ChemEurJ` in [`chembst`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chembst).

   ```
   \documentclass[british]{article}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{babel}

   \usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}

   \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
   @article{becke,
     author  = {Becke, Axel D.},
     title   = {Density-functional thermochemistry. {III.}
                {The} role of exact exchange},
     journal = {J. Chem. Phys.},
     volume  = {98},
     number  = {7},
     pages   = {5648-5652},
     year    = {1993},
     doi     = {10.1063/1.464913},
   }
   @article{perdew,
     title   = {Generalized Gradient Approximation Made Simple},
     author  = {Perdew, John P. and Burke, Kieron and Ernzerhof, Matthias},
     journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
     volume  = {77},
     number  = {18},
     pages   = {3865-3868},
     year    = {1996},
     month   = 8,
     doi     = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865},
   }
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}
   \cite{perdew,becke}
   \bibliographystyle{ChemEurJ}
   \bibliography{\jobname}
   \end{document}
   ```

Both bundles are available in both MikTeX and TeX live and can be installed through the TeX distribution if they are not present already (i.e. via `tlmgr` or the TeX Live Utility with TeX live and via the MikTeX Console in MikTeX).

Both styles produce the following in the MWE

[image: J. P. Perdew, K. Burke, M. Ernzerhof, Phys. Rev. Lett. 1996, 77, 3865–3868.//A. D. Becke, J. Chem. Phys. 1993, 98, 5648–5652.]

[Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright), the maintainer of `rsc`, discusses the two styles in his answer to [bibtex-style "angewandte" and double citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223334/35864).

---

If you want to use `biblatex`, you can use `chem-angew` from the [`biblatex-chem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem) bundle

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{becke,
  author  = {Becke, Axel D.},
  title   = {Density-functional thermochemistry. {III.}
             {The} role of exact exchange},
  journal = {J. Chem. Phys.},
  volume  = {98},
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {5648-5652},
  year    = {1993},
  doi     = {10.1063/1.464913},
}
@article{perdew,
  title   = {Generalized Gradient Approximation Made Simple},
  author  = {Perdew, John P. and Burke, Kieron and Ernzerhof, Matthias},
  journal = {Phys. Rev. Lett.},
  volume  = {77},
  number  = {18},
  pages   = {3865-3868},
  year    = {1996},
  month   = 8,
  doi     = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.77.3865},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{perdew,becke}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```